# Clone project from GitHub

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea

I'm trying to integrate GitHub with IntelliJ IDE.

When I want to clone a project from my GitHub account, IntelliJ shows this message:

```
Clone failed: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I tested the connection to my account when I configured the GitHub settings on IntelliJ and it seems to be OK.

I've tried to publish a new project from IntelliJ, but it shows this message:

```
Can't finish GitHub sharing process
Successfully created project 'Grupo-01-12' on GitHub, but initial push failed:
Could not read from remote repository.
```

What could be going on?

EDIT: [image]

Comment: You *sure* your credentials are alright with GitHub?  What does `ssh -vT git@github.com` say?

Comment: @Makoto see the edit.

Comment: That doesn't quite answer my question.  That indicates you have your account credentials stored away, but your account credentials aren't the same as your SSH key, which is what I suspect is the issue.  Run the command I provided and let me know whether or not it's rejected or accepted your private key.

Comment: where I run the command?